# Django formset - empty kwargs

Tags: python, django, formset, keyword-argument

I am trying to initialize a Django formset with an addition parameter to pass on the forms in the formset. However when i initialize the formset with formset factory and pass the variable to it. the Kwargs is always empty

forms.py

```
from django.forms.formsets import BaseFormSet
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory

class BaseCIFormSet(BaseFormSet):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print kwargs
        self.grn_id = kwargs.pop('grn_id', None)
        super(BaseCIFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _construct_forms(self):
        self.forms = []
        for i in xrange(self.total_form_count()):
            self.forms.append(self._construct_form(i, grn_id=self.grn_id))
```

Views.py

```
data['form-TOTAL_FORMS'] = count
data['form-INITIAL_FORMS'] = count
data['form-MAX_NUM_FORMS'] = ''

CIFormSet = formset_factory(CIForm, formset=BaseCIFormSet, extra=(count), can_delete=True)
formset = CIFormSet(data, grn_id)
```

The "print kwargs" always returns and empty dict {} and the kwargs.pop always goes into default. Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't. The parameters you pass are not named parameters, and are therefore stored in the `*args`pointer. To get them into the `**kwargs` dict you'd have to do this

```
formset = CIFormSet(data=data,grn_id=grn_id)
```

Comment: Thanks! fixed my issue everything is working like a charm now. And i learned something i didn't knew... second thumbs up for that!