# Django Forms: Empty kwargs from Views

Tags: python, django, forms, parameters, keyword-argument

I am trying to initialize a Django form with a parameter from a view. However when i try to use the **kwargs** in the form's **init**, i get that it's always empty. Why could it be? Am i missing something?

My view (filename: “FirstView.py”):

```
def create_userStory(request, proyect_id):

if request.method=='POST':
    auxForm = UserStoryForm(request.POST, proyect_id=proyect_id)
```

My form (filename: “forms.py”):

```
class UserStoryForm(forms.ModelForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    proyectId = kwargs.pop('proyect_id', None)
    super(UserStoryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    team = Team.objects.get(proyect_id=proyectId)
```

I tried debugging/printing the **kwargs** in my form, but i always get **{}**, meaning that the parameter from the view did not pass.

Previously i tryied to follow these existing questions:

[django form: Passing parameter from view.py to forms gives out error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723465/django-form-passing-parameter-from-view-py-to-forms-gives-out-error)

[Django Forms: pass parameter to form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660037/django-forms-pass-parameter-to-form)

[Django formset - empty kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893696/django-formset-empty-kwargs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.
After one hour of searching (...), I found that  in my call to `__init__` :

`myModelForm(request.POST, namedargument=val)`

`val` was in fact `None` when I thought that it contained a value.

Then, for `__init__`: if `namedargument=None` ==> `namedargument` alone. 
And the `kwargs` becomes `args` !

That's why the kwargs was empty.

So, check your value you're passing, it's probably `None` by mistake.

(I know, it's a 2 years answer but I would have loved to find this one hour ago...)

Answer (score 0):

The `*args` and `**kwargs` in the signature are use to catch arguments, that have not been taken by other defined argument positions.
All untaken unnamed arguments will be placed a list `args` and all named arguments in a dictionary `kwargs`. You can change the names if you like.

An example:

```
def function_1(a, b, *args, **kwargs):
```

A call like

```
function_1(1, 2, 3, 4, c=5, d=6)
```

will result in the following variables available inside function_1:

```
a = 1
b = 2
args = (3, 4)
kwargs = {'c': 5, 'd': 6}
```

So applied on your question that means that as long you are don't have any  named arguments, you will have an empty `kwargs`.

Comment: he's got named arguments: proyect_id:  ` auxForm = UserStoryForm(request.POST, proyect_id=proyect_id)` . So I don't think the problem was from here.